# How to replace OpenCV handling of binary image data in Flask with Pillow

Tags: python, opencv, python-imaging-library

I'm currently using OpenCV to handle an image passed through to a Flask API implementation as binary data and I would like to replace it with Pillow.

The data is passed through like this:

```
# load image
img = open('test1.jpg', 'rb').read()
# send image and get response
response = requests.post(test_url, data=img, headers=headers)
```

And handled in Flask with Open CV like this:

```
# route http posts to this method
@app.route('/api/test', methods=['POST'])
def test():
    r = request
    # convert string of image data to uint8
    nparr = np.fromstring(r.data, np.uint8)
    # decode image
    img = cv2.imdecode(nparr, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution was as follows:

```
# route http posts to this method
@app.route('/api/test', methods=['POST'])
def test():
    r = request
    # convert string of image data to uint8
    nparr = np.fromstring(r.data, np.uint8)
    # decode image
    img = Image.open(io.BytesIO(nparr))
```